# execute a call in batch file to a lable with variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, label, call

It should be a simple thing, but I'm not getting it

I want to do a call inside a batch file to a label using a variable as a parameter, something like this:

```
echo off
set TEST=message text
call :MESSAGE %TEST% more text
:MESSAGE
echo %1
```

what I get is this:

```
C:\>echo off
message
ECHO is off.
```

Comment: Explanation of what's happening in your example: `message` comes from the subroutine call, where %1 is the 'message' part of %TEST%. The next output `ECHO is off.` comes from when the execution returns after the subroutine call and %1 is now unset; so it's just executing `echo` the second time. Try it with `echo %1 %2 %3 %4` and you should get a `message text more text`. You need flow control as shown in the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The problem is that in the 'real life' this peace of code is to be called many times with different messages, not always with the same number of arguments. The point of this is code is exactly to do a message sob routine, because the message itself is to be displayed to the screen and at least 3 different log files. So, would reduced the code in many lines.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use %* instead of %1 ... simple as that!

Answer (score 2):

`:message` is a label. There is no boundary to avoid the execution to enter the code after it, but this time the code is reached without a parameter to echo and from here the `ECHO off`

```
@echo off
  set TEST=message text
  call :MESSAGE %TEST% more text
  goto :eof

:MESSAGE
  echo %1
```

Now the `goto :eof` (or `exit /b` to leave the batch file or `exit` to close the console) avoid the execution to continue into the code after the label

Comment: or use `%*` instead of `%1` if you want all the text (`message text more text`)

Comment: That is Stephan! Thank you :)